# TFGPT2LMHeadModel unknown location

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I have been playing around with tensorflow (CPU), and some language model'ing - and it have been a blast so far - everything working great.
But after watching my old CPU slowly getting killed from all the model-training - i decided it was time to  finally get some use out of my RTX 2080. I have been following the guide from [washinton university](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-jul-2020.ipynb):.  Pretty quickly i got tensorflow-gpu running, ran it on some light grade-prediction and stuff like that.

But when i got to running GPT2 language model, i ran into some minor problems. I start by tokenizing the data:

```
from tokenizers.models import BPE
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.decoders import ByteLevel as ByteLevelDecoder
from tokenizers.normalizers import NFKC, Sequence
from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import ByteLevel
from tokenizers.trainers import BpeTrainer

class BPE_token(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE())
    self.tokenizer.normalizer = Sequence([
        NFKC()
    ])
    self.tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = ByteLevel()
    self.tokenizer.decoder = ByteLevelDecoder()

def bpe_train(self, paths):
    trainer = BpeTrainer(vocab_size=50000, show_progress=True, inital_alphabet=ByteLevel.alphabet(),         special_tokens=[
        "<s>",
        "<pad>",
        "</s>",
        "<unk>",
        "<mask>"
    ])
    self.tokenizer.train(trainer, paths)

def save_tokenizer(self, location, prefix=None):
    if not os.path.exists(location):
        os.makedirs(location)
    self.tokenizer.model.save(location, prefix)

# ////////// TOKENIZE DATA ////////////
from pathlib import Pa th
import os# the folder 'text' contains all the files
paths = [str(x) for x in Path("./da_corpus/").glob("**/*.txt")]
tokenizer = BPE_token()# train the tokenizer model
tokenizer.bpe_train(paths)# saving the tokenized data in our specified folder
save_path = 'tokenized_data'
tokenizer.save_tokenizer(save_path)
```

Code above works perfectly and tokenizes the data - just like with tensorflow (CPU). After having my data tokenized i start to train my model - but before it even gets start, i get the following ImportError:

```
from transformers import GPT2Config, TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer # loading tokenizer from the   saved model path
ImportError: cannot import name 'TFGPT2LMHeadModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)
```

Transformers package seems to be installed correctly in the site-packages lib, and i seem to be able to use the other transformers - but not **TFGPT2LMHeadModel**
I have read everything on google and [hugging.co](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) - tried different versions of tensorflow-gpu, transformers, tokenizers and alot of other packages -  -  sadly nothing helps.

**Packages:**

- Python, 3.7.1
- Tensorflow 2.1.0
- Tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0
- Tensorflow-base 2.1.0
- Tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0
- Transformers 4.2.2
- Tokenizers 0.9.4
- cudnn 7.6.5
- cudatoolkit 10.1.243

Comment: Please add the output of `transformers.__version__`.

Comment: @cronoik Added! sorry, should ofc. have thought about that - kinda important :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by installing tensorflow-gpu=2.3.0 & cuda 10.1

Following this guide:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tensorflow-2-3-0-with-gpu-support-on-windows-10-f975a552ea7c

Use this command to install gpu2.3.0:
python -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the below command that works as expected.

```
# installing Transformers and TensorFlow 2.0 in one line
!pip install transformers[tf-gpu]
```